# Could not find com.appnext.sdk:ads:2.7.1.473

Tags: android, gradle, build.gradle, yandex

To test Yandex Ad SDK I created a new project in Android Studio

And according to their docs I added the following repositories to `settings.gradle`:

```
maven { url "https://android-sdk.is.com/" }
maven { url "https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle" }
maven { url "https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea"}
maven { url "https://sdk.tapjoy.com/"}
```

so `settings.gradle` content is:

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()

        maven { url "https://android-sdk.is.com/" }
        maven { url "https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle" }
        maven { url "https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea"}
        maven { url "https://sdk.tapjoy.com/"}
    }
}
rootProject.name = "My Application"
include ':app'
```

and added

```
implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:6.3.0.0'
```

to `build.gradle`:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.myapplication'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapplication"
        minSdk 24
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'

    implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:6.3.0.0'
}
```

And when I tried to build the project in Android Studio I got the following errors:

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 9 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:dataBindingMergeDependencyArtifactsDebug'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
  > Could not find com.appnext.sdk:ads:2.7.1.473.
    Searched in the following locations:
      - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/appnext/sdk/ads/2.7.1.473/ads-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/appnext/sdk/ads/2.7.1.473/ads-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://android-sdk.is.com/com/appnext/sdk/ads/2.7.1.473/ads-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle/com/appnext/sdk/ads/2.7.1.473/ads-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea/com/appnext/sdk/ads/2.7.1.473/ads-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://sdk.tapjoy.com/com/appnext/sdk/ads/2.7.1.473/ads-2.7.1.473.pom
    Required by:
        project :app > com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:6.3.0.0 > com.yandex.ads.mediation:mobileads-appnext:2.7.1.473.0
  > Could not find com.appnext.sdk:banners:2.7.1.473.
    Searched in the following locations:
      - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/appnext/sdk/banners/2.7.1.473/banners-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/appnext/sdk/banners/2.7.1.473/banners-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://android-sdk.is.com/com/appnext/sdk/banners/2.7.1.473/banners-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle/com/appnext/sdk/banners/2.7.1.473/banners-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea/com/appnext/sdk/banners/2.7.1.473/banners-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://sdk.tapjoy.com/com/appnext/sdk/banners/2.7.1.473/banners-2.7.1.473.pom
    Required by:
        project :app > com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:6.3.0.0 > com.yandex.ads.mediation:mobileads-appnext:2.7.1.473.0
  > Could not find com.appnext.sdk:native-ads2:2.7.1.473.
    Searched in the following locations:
      - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/appnext/sdk/native-ads2/2.7.1.473/native-ads2-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/appnext/sdk/native-ads2/2.7.1.473/native-ads2-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://android-sdk.is.com/com/appnext/sdk/native-ads2/2.7.1.473/native-ads2-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle/com/appnext/sdk/native-ads2/2.7.1.473/native-ads2-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea/com/appnext/sdk/native-ads2/2.7.1.473/native-ads2-2.7.1.473.pom
      - https://sdk.tapjoy.com/com/appnext/sdk/native-ads2/2.7.1.473/native-ads2-2.7.1.473.pom
    Required by:
        project :app > com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:6.3.0.0 > com.yandex.ads.mediation:mobileads-appnext:2.7.1.473.0
  > Could not find com.chartboost:chartboost-sdk:9.3.1.
    Searched in the following locations:
      - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/chartboost/chartboost-sdk/9.3.1/chartboost-sdk-9.3.1.pom
      - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/com/chartboost/chartboost-sdk/9.3.1/chartboost-sdk-9.3.1.pom
      - https://android-sdk.is.com/com/chartboost/chartboost-sdk/9.3.1/chartboost-sdk-9.3.1.pom
      - https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle/com/chartboost/chartboost-sdk/9.3.1/chartboost-sdk-9.3.1.pom
      - https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea/com/chartboost/chartboost-sdk/9.3.1/chartboost-sdk-9.3.1.pom
      - https://sdk.tapjoy.com/com/chartboost/chartboost-sdk/9.3.1/chartboost-sdk-9.3.1.pom

...
BUILD FAILED in 31s
21 actionable tasks: 9 executed, 12 up-to-date
```

What do these errors mean? What can be wrong? Is it possible to fix them?

I tried to consult with their support, but they did not help.

Comment: Did you also add Java8 support as required in the [documentation](https://ads.yandex.com/helpcenter/en/dev/android/quick-start-mm)? Also, what version of Kotlin are you using? **Notice also that you added urls in the wrong place. You weren't supposed to add them to the settings.gradle, but rather to the build.gradle of the application.**

Comment: @tomerpacific see full `build.gradle` content in the updated post. Where should I add URLs in `build.gradle`?

Comment: @tomerpacific It is unlikely that I added URLs in a wrong place, because if I change SDK version to `implementation 'com.yandex.android:mobileads-mediation:6.0.0.0'` the build succeeds. It is probably something specific to version 6.3.0.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://ads.yandex.com/helpcenter/en/dev/android/quick-start-mm), since you are integrating the mediation of Yandex, you need to remove all the urls you added in settings.gradle and add them in the build.gradle file of your project module. It is step 2.4 in their integration document.

```
Add the following code to the build.gradle file in your app's module:

// IronSource
maven {
       url 'https://android-sdk.is.com/'
}

// Pangle
maven {
       url 'https://artifact.bytedance.com/repository/pangle'
}

// Tapjoy
maven {
       url "https://sdk.tapjoy.com/"
}

// Mintegral
maven {
       url "https://dl-maven-android.mintegral.com/repository/mbridge_android_sdk_oversea"
}

// Chartboost
maven {
       url "https://cboost.jfrog.io/artifactory/chartboost-ads/"
}

// AppNext
maven {
      url "https://dl.appnext.com/"
}
```

They also state there that:

> For each adapter, the latest compatible version is selected
> automatically.

Comment: If I add this code at the top level of my `app\build.gradle` I get the following build errors:  `Could not find method maven() for arguments [build_3wdu550zckbw03a4xeu294o0m$_run_closure1@58446c68] on project ':app' of type org.gradle.api.Project`. Probably I add this under some specific node. My understanding was that I add them under `repositories` node.

Comment: @AlexeyStarinsky - Check the [example project](https://github.com/yandexmobile/yandex-ads-sdk-android/blob/master/YandexMobileAdsExample/build.gradle.kts). You need to add it in the project build.gradle under repositories.